# picture of dq axis in multi pole motor

Tags: electric-machine, pmsm

How does the dq axis of multi pole motor look like? Typically [online images search](https://www.bing.com/images/search?view=detailV2&ccid=ZzFjfQ8q&id=7202517A1FBDE028270B29A60B5A8EEF2DF2F5D0&thid=OIP.ZzFjfQ8qURsirrNZHQ6ncAHaF9&mediaurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mathworks.com%2Fhelp%2Fphysmod%2Fsps%2Fref%2Fpermmag_syncmotor_construction.png&exph=247&expw=307&q=dq%20axis%20pmsm&simid=607997030783726121&ck=44A19C9D5B60BF8A82EDE120B6941F5F&selectedIndex=11&FORM=IRPRST&ajaxhist=0) show dq axis for motor with one pole. Consider a 4 pole stator PMSM motor. Will there be multiple dq axis for each pole pair? Will dq axis be orthogonal electrical angle or by mechanical angle?

Comment: (I'm relieved the picture shows one *pole pair*.)

Answer (score 0):

AC motors are analyzed based on an equivalent line-neutral circuit for one phase. The analysis is based on the electrical angle of rotation. The motor is assumed to be constructed such that every pole is identical, so it is not necessary to consider multiple dq axis.

Comment: I am trying to physically map the dq axis to mechanical angle. I understanding is that, during control of motor, the stator flux line is aligned to q axis and rotor's axis is aligned to d axis. if these flux are orthogonal ,then maximum torque is established. My particular confusion is, if there are multiple poles and then wouldn't the equivalent dq axis is getting squeezed, and then rotor and stator flux wouldn'd be orthogonal, right? Maybe i am confused. If so can you help with where i am getting this wrong.

Answer (score 0):

please see this, if the pole pair of rotor and stator is different or have a remainder , then iDon't know

### https://www.mdpi.com/1996-1073/9/8/580/pdf

[image: -------------------------------------]

Comment: Can you provide a better explaination?